# hover event firing twice when child is hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am mocking up a simple multi-level drop down box and cannot figure out how to get the hover event to fire only once when a `li` is hovered. The hover event fires twice when the `a` tag inside of the list-item is hovered.

Here is a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem. I've added extra padding around the `a` tag to show how the event is fired twice. If just the padding is hovered, the event will fire once, but once the `a` tag is hovered, it will fire again.

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropit">
    <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-thing 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-thing 2</a>
           <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-sub-thing 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-sub-thing 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('ul.dropit li').on('mouseover', function(event) {
        $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        $sub = $target.children('ul').first();
        $sub.slideToggle();
    }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
        $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        $target.children('ul').first().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5ENy4/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ENy4/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('ul.dropit li').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
        $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        $sub = $target.children('ul').first();
        $sub.slideToggle();
    }).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
        $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        $target.children('ul').first().slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

`mouseover` will fire when you hover over a child element.

`mouseenter` fires only once no matter how many children are hovered.

Answer (score 5):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dUpN/4/)***

just use `.hover()`

And additionally **to prevent ugly slides buildups** on repeated hover movements
use: `.stop()`

```
$('.dropit li:has("ul")').hover(function() {
    $('>ul', this).stop().slideToggle();
});
```